# Javascript: what's the point of RegExp.compile()?

Tags: javascript, regex, compilation

I've got a situation where I want to get a regexp from the user and run it against a few thousand input strings. In the manual I found that the `RegExp` object has a `.compile()` method which is used to speed things up ins such cases. But why do I have to pass the regexp string to it again if I already passed them in the constructor? Perhaps constructor does the `compile()` itself?

Answer (score 100, accepted):

The [`RegExp().compile()` method is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/compile).  It's basically the same as the constructor, which I assume is why it was deprecated.  You should only have to use the constructor nowadays.

In other words, you used to be able to do this:

```
var regexp = new RegExp("pattern");
regexp.compile("new pattern");
```

But nowadays it is not any different from simply calling:

```
var regexp = new RegExp("pattern");
regexp = new RegExp("new pattern");
```

Answer (score 7):

And with Opera 11, running `RegExp.compile()` will actually cause errors.

Evidently, when Opera "compiles" a regex, it wraps the `re.source` string in forward slashes (e.g. `re.source == "^(.)"` becomes `"/^(.)/"`). If you manually compile the regex, Opera doesn't recognize this fact and goes ahead and compiles it again (`re.source` becomes `"//^(.)//"`). Each compile results in an extra set of forward slashes, which changes the meaning of the regular expression and results in errors.

Answer (score 6):

You have to compile your regex first to use it if you are using `/`, try this out:

```js
var regex=new RegExp('/[a-zA-Z]/')

console.log("not compiled with escape /", regex.test("ciao") )

regex.compile()

console.log("compiled", regex.test("ciao") )

var regex=new RegExp('[a-zA-Z]')

console.log("not compiled, but no escape /", regex.test("ciao") )
```

Comment: Wow, that's interesting. I just checked it, and you're right! It's not mentioned in MDN though.

Comment: You shouldn't use forward slashes when using the `RegExp` constructor. Forward slashes are used to start and end `RegExp` *literal*, they are not part of the pattern (unless you actually mean to match literal forward slashes). IMO, this is actually buggy behaviour in `compile` and shouldn't be relied on.

Comment: To make the point - `new RegExp('/[a-zA-Z]/').test('/a/')` *is* `true`. The forward slashes are properly interpreted as part of the pattern. 

`compile()` actually changes this (Chrome 85), which I don't think it should. However, `compile()` itself is now marked deprecated in MDN.

Answer (score 4):

As far as i can tell all RegExp.compile does is replace the underlying regular expression of a RegExp object.  I think compile may have had value in the past, but all modern JS engines "compile" the regex on first call and cache that "compiled" version.

Comment: Which engines exactly do cache regular expressions? And do they always do it? How long is an expression kept in cache? I'm particularly interested in V8.