# Compiling regular expressions for google-code-prettify

Tags: javascript, regex

We are working on an extension to google-code-prettify which does the code-coloring for source-code on a webpage. We have a very long list of keywords (approx 4000) in Mathematica and while the performance is still very good, I wondered whether I can speed things up.

The regular expression for our keyword list looks like this

```
var keywords = 'AbelianGroup|Abort|AbortKernels|AbortProtect|Above|Abs|Absolute|\
AbsoluteCurrentValue|AbsoluteDashing|AbsoluteFileName|AbsoluteOptions|\
AbsolutePointSize|AbsoluteThickness|AbsoluteTime|AbsoluteTiming|AccountingForm';
new RegExp('^(?:' + keywords + ')\\b')
```

Can such an *or*-ed regex be made faster when it is compiled? Would it in the first place make sense to compile it, since google-code-prettify is a JavaScript running on the server. I don't know whether this script is loaded freshly every time a web-page is loaded. In this case, it is maybe not worth the overhead to compile it.

Comment: Presumably you _are_ assigning the regex to another variable and re-using it rather than calling `new RegExp` every time?

Comment: I just split this for better readability. Look here https://github.com/halirutan/Mathematica-Source-Highlighting/blob/master/mathematica-source-highlighter.user.js

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `google-code-prettify` runs on the client (it's a script; the source is requested from the server by the browser).
2. Creating the `RegExp` object *does* compile it, at runtime.

In other words, just leave it as-is.

Comment: Ok, now as you say it seems obvious that the script has to run on the client since it is just fetched like the whole web-page. Additionally, I must have missed this post http://stackoverflow.com/a/884784/1078614 which would have answered my question. Anyway, thank you very much.