# Javascript regex .test fails to reject after applying .compile()

Tags: javascript, regex

I am relatively new to javascript.
Following code explains my issue:

```
var termList = ["style", "model"];
var nodeValidRegexStr = "(?:" + termList.join("|") + ")+"

var nodeValidRegex = RegExp(nodeValidRegexStr);    
nodeValidRegex.test("mode")
false

nodeValidRegex.compile()
nodeValidRegex.test("mode")
true
```

Can someone figure out whats goes wrong after compile() ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: FWIW, `.compile` is deprecated: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Deprecated_and_obsolete_features#RegExp_Methods.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/884762/javascript-whats-the-point-of-regexp-compile Note that the pattern after calling `.compile()` looks like `/(?:)/` (at least in Chrome)

Comment: ^^^ which matches everything.

Comment: Thanks for the info. So, if .compile() is deprecated does it mean that RegExp() itself always compiles the regex?

Comment: Curious what it is you're actually trying to do? What's the end result here?